# Embedding Dashboard in a Web based tool

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

Can you embed a power bi dashboard in a webpage which will change its source connection based on some value in the webpage?

I have a web based tool where I need to build my visuals. I will get data from an Oracle Database staging table. The visual is to be build from staging table. However, I need to use that staging table as source which user has asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Data Source using [Configure credentials programmatically for Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/configure-credentials?tabs=sdk3)

however, since the data source will change for all the users, it won't work in your scenario.

You can create reports with different sources in separate workspace, and change the embedded report instead of changing the data source.

**References :**

1. [Power BI Embedded Update Datasources API](https://learn.microsoft.comrest/api/power-bi/gateways/update-datasource)